# TYPO3 Extbase sorting child object by another field as "sorting" (f.e. datetime)

Tags: sorting, typo3, parent-child, extbase

There's the way to sort childs via `'foreign_sortby' => 'sorting'` which works perfectly. But it's not possible to use that in my case:

I don't wanna sort it via `'sorting'` - I need to sort it via `'datetime'` and that leads into problems if I set that as `'foreign_sortby'`, because it overwrites the field when I save the parent. I seams to fill that with sorting integers which makes totally sense, but destroys my entries.

There's as well a `'foreign_default_sortby'` which seamed to be perfect for me, but that just sorts the backend, not the frontend. :/ Any Idea?

I need the first and the last child in my model, after sorting via dates - sometimes they are not created in the right order, that's why it's important to sort that first.

TCA:

```php
    'events' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:database/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_database_domain_model_production.events',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_database_domain_model_event',
            'foreign_field' => 'production',
            'foreign_default_sortby' => 'date ASC',
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'default' => 0,
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 1,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'bottom',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1,
                'enabledControls' => [
                    'info' => true,
                    'new' => true,
                    'dragdrop' => true,
                    'sort' => true,
                    'hide' => true,
                    'delete' => true,
                    'localize' => false,
                ],

            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Can you please also add the full TCA of your field?

Comment: just added the tca ;) hope that helps. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed Extbase does not support `foreign_default_sortby`. (There is a [feature request for this in the TYPO3 Forge](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/64197).) And unfortunately also `foreign_table_where` is ignored even though this is actually added to the `ColumnMap` built by the `DataMapFactory`.

So your only options are to perform the sorting in your own code, e.g. in the getter of your `ObjectStorage` property. Then you can quite easily get the first and last object in your template or some custom getters like `getFirstEvent()` and `getLastEvent()` / `getMostRecentEvent()`. Notice that this requires loading all related objects which can impose a penalty on your memory usage depending on your usecase.

Aside from that you could also add custom methods to your `EventRepository` like `findFirstByProduction()` and `findLastByProduction()` given that `Production` is your local domain model with the `events` relation. This mostly makes sense for a detail view where you process a single `Production` instance anways.

Comment: yeah I thought about that, but that just makes sense in a single view as you say. it's more about a solution for list-views. But thx for your infos.

Answer (score 0):

> **This might be the ugly solution but working one..**

[image]

**Let's consider following scenario**

```
$multiObjects = $blog->getPosts(); 

//first debug output in the screenshot
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($multiObjects); 

//Convert that into array (inner objects will remain the same)
$multiArray = [];
foreach ($multiObjects as $multiObject) {
    $multiArray[] = $multiObject;
}

//Second debug output in the screenshot
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($multiArray); 

//Now we can apply usort over it
usort($multiArray, function($first,$second){
    return strcmp($second->getUid(), $first->getUid());
});

//Here child objects within array will be sorted in descending order of their UIDs
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($multiArray);
```

> **Note : This will be required in case where records are fetched with createQuery method of repository**

**The final output**

[image]

Comment: Yeah sure. I always can do things manually. But it's a question of resources cause I add an additional sorting although you could already get a sorted query before.

In my case we're talking about thousands of entries. It would work, but it is much slower with a huge amount of data. Would be really nice if the core team would implement a working sorting for childs - out of the sort by mode that always wants to make an automatically sorting.

Comment: Now you can make childs sortable and sort them manually. You can sort childs in the backend tool as you want to, but you cannot tell the system what's the sorting for frontend, so you have to sort everything in fluid again. If you wanna have a first or last object then, but in the wanted sorting it becomes to get very tricky.

Comment: For my project I added now additional fields which have already the right objects as single-relation. That makes the system much faster. So I use an action to update all important relations with a click. That sets the first and last child as fixed field entries and adds some other fields as well.

I was just confused that typo3 doesn't have a nice way for that. I guess I'm not alone with this sort of needed features. And you have a getObject()->first() and getObject()->last() [or end()]. But that's senseless if I cannot tell the system how to sort the child's.  At least sometimes.