Override sorting field in Extbase MM m:n connection on child table
I'm struggling with a m:n connection in TYPO3 Extbase.
I want to override the sorting of the MM table because it will not be used by the editor, so actually I get the sorting by time of adding a new contact. I would like to be able to sort the contacts by last name.
I tried adding this in the Repository of the main table but no change:
protected $defaultOrderings = [
    'title' =>   \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
    'kontakte.nachname' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
];

Default_sortby is configured in the kontakte-table and it shows correctly in the backend but on the Detailview of the Main-Table the kontakte are always sorted by the sorting field of the MM table and not the value of the field nachname in the connected table.
What am I doing wrong?
This is my TCA of the master table:
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_alpintecbaustelle_domain_model_kontakte',
            'foreign_default_sortby' => 'nachname',
            'MM' => 'tx_alpintecbaustelle_anlage_kontakte_mm',

and the one of the subtable. Here when I list the records it gets sorted correctly:
    'default_sortby' => 'nachname',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    'enablecolumns' => [
    ],


Sounds like the same requirement as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/61918662/6783328.
In the meanwhile this mentioned feature has been resolved: have a look at foreign_default_sortby

This is my TCA. Tried this ..doesn't change the outcome:
'config' => [
'type' => 'select',
'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
'foreign_table' => 'tx_alpintecbaustelle_domain_model_kontakte',
'foreign_default_sortby' => 'nachname',
'MM' => 'tx_alpintecbaustelle_anlage_kontakte_mm',

as comments can not be formatted, edit your question and add your configuration.

Sure. Added them. In the meantime I implemented a PHP-sort of the subobject in the showAction...
